# Confirm validity of JMH benchmarks of for loop and streams performance

Tags: java, java-stream, jmh

I decided I wanted to perform some measurements of simple streams operations, comparing them to corresponding pre-streams iteration structures.

I have an ArrayList of a certain length, such that all the list elements are three-character strings.

Here are the related benchmark methods for this:

```
@Benchmark
public long shortLengthConstantSizeFor() {
    long count   = 0;
    for (String val : shortLengthListConstantSize) {
        if (val.length() == 3) { ++ count; }
    }
    return count;
}

@Benchmark
public long shortLengthConstantSizeForEach() {
    IntHolder   intHolder   = new IntHolder();
    shortLengthListConstantSize.forEach(s -> { if (s.length() == 3) ++ intHolder.value; } );
    return intHolder.value;
}

@Benchmark
public long shortLengthConstantSizeLambda() {
    return shortLengthListConstantSize.stream().filter(s -> s.length() == 3).count();
}

@Benchmark
public long shortLengthConstantSizeLambdaParallel() {
    return shortLengthListConstantSize.stream().parallel().filter(s -> s.length() == 3).count();
}
```

All I want to confirm with the community is whether these are "functionally equivalent", and will really be measuring what they appear to be measuring.  I'm not providing the measurements here, because that would be a distraction.

Note that "shortLength" refers to a "short list".  I also have several blocks of these methods, with different length lists, up to one with 300k elements.

Comment: post the entire code please

Comment: I'm going to post the code and measurements in a different posting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If by "functional equivalence" you mean that each method performs the same function or measurement, including side effects - it appears to be so.

One could argue that in the second method you should use `LongHolder` and not `IntHolder` to match function's codomain. But if your "value" is, in reality, a `long` in this class - then it's a pass.

It is worth mentioning that `count()` is just a shorthand for `map(x -> 1L).sum()` but it changes nothing for this benchmark.